# Wait for Callback inside AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, okhttp

I'd like to do some work in `AsyncTask` including some server requests for downloading small files. When download is done continue logic inside `AsyncTask` and when all stuff is done I get the result in activity. Everything is working good but my `AsyncTask`  is not waiting for callback method:

```
public class AsyncOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String linkUrl = params[0];

    functionDoStuff(linkUrl);

    return "Executed";
}

public void functionDoStuff(String urlLink) {

    ... code ...

    String str = getFile(urlLink);

    !!! is not waiting for result !!!

    ... use 'str' ...

}

private String getFile(String urlLink) {
    String savedFileDestination = null;

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    final Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(urlLink")
                    .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new com.squareup.okhttp.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
            //something goes wrong
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(com.squareup.okhttp.Response response) throws IOException {

            //get stream
            InputStream inputStream = response.body().byteStream();

            //this method save file and return file path
            savedFileDestination = saveFileMethod(inputStream);
        }
    });

        return savedFileDestination;
    }

}
```

How can I wait for this callback to continue logic in `functiobDoStuff()` ?

Comment: *How can I wait for this callback to continut logic in functiobDoStuff() ?* with some semaphore ...but then ... but then what is the point of callback ... also there is no point(nor even sens) of using one async method inside another async method

Comment: can you elaborate this question please ?

Comment: Try to use interface concept. Create a method onComplete(String msg) in interface and call the method in functionDoStuff(). Write your logic inside the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Selvin is right, I have to make my request **synchronous** and my 'waiting problem' is gone!

The only change is into `getFile()` method, it should be smth like:

```
   private void getFile(String urlLink) {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    final Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(urlLink)
            .build();

    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        if (response!=null){
            InputStream inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
            saveFile(inputStream);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put all the stuff inside onResponse method.Because onResponse method work asyncronusly

Comment: yes , there is not any sense of using a async method in another async method.